# Cropping and resizing images so they fit an canvas in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, user-interface, resize, crop

We are looking for a solution for a web application to resize images based on a predefined canvas. Similar to Linkedin Profile image (square) and the page header. I want to define the canvas (aspect ratio), and the user uploads an image and then positions and resizes it to fit the canvas perfectly. Then the user clicks save, and that part of the image is stored.

How to achieve this? We are using Rails. We also are open to third-party solutions.
Thanks, Steven

We tried to solve it with code but we really need an attractive and intuitive solution to fix this. Just like Linkedin is doing it.

Comment: This is not the sort of question StackOverflow is designed to facilitate. Take a read through [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Voted to close.